# jQuery and regex for adding icons to specific links?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery to add icons to specific links, e.g. a myspace icon for sites starting with `http://myspace.com` etc.

However, I can't figure out how to use regular expressions (if that's even possible here), to make jQuery recognize the link either with or without "www." (I'm very bad at regular expressions in general).

Here are two examples:

```
    $("a[href^='http://www.last.fm']").addClass("lastfm").attr("target", "_blank");
    $("a[href^='http://livejournal.com']").addClass("livejournal").attr("target", "_blank");
```

They work fine, but I now I want the last.fm link to work with `http://last.fm`,  `http://www.last.fm` and `http://www.lastfm.de`. Currently it only works for www.last.fm.

I also would like to make the livejournal link work with subdomains links like `http://username.livejournal.com`

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo)'s answer is best if you want strict matching, regex is the way to go.  If you're a bit looser and just need to match, you can stick with selectors.  For the first you can use multiple selectors:

```
$("a[href^='http://last.fm'], a[href^='http://www.last.fm'], a[href^='http://www.lastfm.de']")
```

For the last, you could switch to a [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
$("a[href*='livejournal.com']")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried the contains selector, but for some reason it's not working :/ 

`$("ul a[href~='livejournal.com']").addClass("livejournal").attr("target", "_blank");`

Comment: @rayne - Opps, my fault, that should be `*=` not `~=`, try changing it in your selector...updated the answer to show the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var icons = {
    "last.fm": "lastfm",
    "lastfm.de": "lastfm",
    "livejournal.com": "livejournal"
};
$("a[href]").each(function(){
    var match;
    if ((match = this.href.match(/^https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)*(\w+\.\w+)(?:$|\/)/)) && icons.hasOwnProperty(match[1])) {
        $(this).addClass(icons[match]).attr("target", "_blank");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. No classes added :/